# Enterprise Architect:- functions or procedures invocations names in Diagrams are not visible

Tags: svn, stored-procedures, enterprise-architect

While creating diagram structure in Enterprise Architect tool, we call other functions or procedures or in other words we invoke those functions or procedures from other packages and then complete our diagrames and commit in svn or may be some other path which ever a person use and in my case we use SVN path to commit,
So my question is when we invoke and commit our complete diagram then after few days in some cases i am talking about, that these invocations are gone and only empty functions box are visible without their corresponding names.
So can anyone help me out how to get those names or invocation back again. and i have attached a snapshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a "known" issue with version control (or xmi export/import in general) that it loses message info when using classifier iso instances.

Although this issue is usually reported in sequence diagrams I can image it could play a role here is as well.

It might be worth to

- Upgrade to the latest version if you haven't done so yet
- Try it with instances instead of classifiers to see if the problem persists
- Report to the issue to Sparx support in a [bug report](http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html)

Comment: For instances also same problem occured.
So, there is no other way in which we can extract all invisible names of instances or classifiers in Enterprise Architect tool?

Comment: please help me out if any solution is there which we can do in our tool itself.

Comment: You better contact Sparx support about this.

Comment: This "known issue" is documented in the help. The flaw is to not forbid classifiers in SDs.